# New Excel.Application Wokbooks.Add

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update code, written by another person and not even managing to make it work on my laptop. The problem is that lines

```
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
oExcel.Workbooks.Add
```

do not create any new workbook **literally nothing happens**, however standalone Workbooks.Add is normally creating new workbook. 
watch window shows that oExcel has "Microsoft Excel" value

---

*Watch : + : oExcel : "Microsoft Excel" : Object/Application : EXCEL_MANAGER.CopyItOver3*

---

What am I doing wrong? My relevant part of code is below.

```
Public Sub CopyItOver3()
On Error GoTo errorHandler
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oExSheet As ObjectDim wbFolder As String
wbFolder = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OUTPUT").Cells(1, 1).Value & "\"
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
oExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set oExSheet = oExcel.Worksheets("Sheet1")
weiter:

  Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.name).Worksheets("OUTPUT").Range("A12:JG7000").Copy

  With oExSheet
  .Range("A1").PasteSpecial (-4163)
End With 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
oExcel.Visible = True
```

I think a new instance is not visible by default.
(But you can see the process in the task manager)

Answer (score 1):

```
oExcel.Visible=True
```

The application is being created but it is running in the background.